# How do I find out what all this traffic is?

Tags: linux, firewall, wireshark, traffic-management, ipcop

I have seen a consistent spike in traffic over my network since Monday morning and I don't know where it's coming from!

I don't have netflow routers (like I would like), I have IPCop firewalls.

Is there any way that's built in to Linux that I can see where the packets are coming from/to?  Like a built in packet capture?

If there's not, how do I go about finding where this traffic's coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get SSH access into the IPCop box and run `iftop`. This should give you a real time view of what's happening.

Comment: I found the jerk that was using all my bandwidth and unplugged him! Thank you, I see myself using this much in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Moving forward I would recommend you looking into a piece of software called [Argus](http://www.qosient.com/argus/index.shtml). It generates flow data, similar to (net|j)flows, by watching either pcap files or a promiscuous network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Run tcpdump on your ipcop and you will see where the traffic is coming from and going to, IP addresses and ports.